# Error with substrate-api-client on local node

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-api-client

I am trying to run the [substrate-api-client](https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client) as a dependency for making RPC calls to the local substrate node. 
But i am getting this error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidMetadata(InvalidVersion)'
```

Any help would be superb.

Comment: You need to have a node using metadata v14 as per this https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client/blob/7b6b822e2826e384346a9ade9585a6f96f4951ca/node-api/src/metadata.rs#L418

Comment: Okay @Jaco I executed a new node. Am getting this error: `thread 'main' panicked at 'called 'Result::unwrap()' on an 'Err' value: Deserializing(Error("missing field 'stateVersion'", line: 1, column: 392))'`

Comment: This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70408593/serde-missing-field-error-when-deserializing-json-file) is somewhat similar to the one i'm facing but not sure how it links to it. Thanks @Jaco for the previous correction. Not facing that error anymore.

Comment: https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client/issues/205#issuecomment-1025060893. This may be a workaround for stateVersion

Answer (score 3):

Substrate-api-client doesn't aim at reverse compatibility. Therefore you may need to work with an older revision if you need legacy metadata. Or upgrade the node and/or runtime you're talking to if you can